# Number of bullish candles across USD for a given timeperiod

Tags: pine-script

For a backtesting study I need to know how many of the most recent closed candles are bullish across USD for a given timeperiod. That is, how many of the most recent closed candles of AUDUSD, USDCAD, EURUSD, GBPUSD, USDJPY, NZDUSD closed approx. at the top of each candle (i.e. with a very little wick or no wick at all), e.g. 4 out of the 6 just mentioned. How could I code this? Below are mentioned (some of) the steps I believe is needed:

```
//@version=4
study(title="test", overlay=false)

timeperiod = "5"

v1 = security("OANDA:AUDUSD", timeframe.period, close)
v2 = security("OANDA:USDCAD", timeframe.period, close)
v3 = security("OANDA:EURUSD", timeframe.period, close)
v4 = security("OANDA:GBPUSD", timeframe.period, close)
v5 = security("OANDA:USDJPY", timeframe.period, close)
v6 = security("OANDA:NZDUSD", timeframe.period, close)

// Identification of bullish candle
// ...
// ...
closeHigherV1 = v1(close > close[1])
        
// Initilization
var bullishCandleCount = 0 
    
// Sum of bullish candles
bullishCandleCount += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study(title="test", overlay=false)

v1Open = security("OANDA:AUDUSD", timeframe.period, open)
v1Close = security("OANDA:AUDUSD", timeframe.period, close)
v2Open = security("OANDA:USDCAD", timeframe.period, open)
v2Close = security("OANDA:USDCAD", timeframe.period, close)
v3Open = security("OANDA:EURUSD", timeframe.period, open)
v3Close = security("OANDA:EURUSD", timeframe.period, close)
v4Open = security("OANDA:GBPUSD", timeframe.period, open)
v4Close = security("OANDA:GBPUSD", timeframe.period, close)
v5Open = security("OANDA:USDJPY", timeframe.period, open)
v5Close = security("OANDA:USDJPY", timeframe.period, close)
v6Open = security("OANDA:NZDUSD", timeframe.period, open)
v6Close = security("OANDA:NZDUSD", timeframe.period, close)

// Identification of bullish candle
closeHigherV1 = v1Open[1] > v1Close[1]
closeHigherV2 = v2Open[1] > v2Close[1]
closeHigherV3 = v3Open[1] > v3Close[1]
closeHigherV4 = v4Open[1] > v4Close[1]
closeHigherV5 = v5Open[1] > v5Close[1]
closeHigherV6 = v6Open[1] > v6Close[1]
        
// Sum of bullish candles
bullishCandleCount = (closeHigherV1 ? 1 : 0) + 
                     (closeHigherV2 ? 1 : 0) + 
                     (closeHigherV3 ? 1 : 0) + 
                     (closeHigherV4 ? 1 : 0) + 
                     (closeHigherV5 ? 1 : 0) + 
                     (closeHigherV6 ? 1 : 0)

plot(bullishCandleCount)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Please let me rephrase the question. If I use the H1 timeframe, then I would like to count how many of the last hour candles of USDXXX are bullish. Say AUDUSD, USDCAD, GBPUSD and USDJPY are bullish and NZDUSD and EURUSD are bearish then the algo should count 4 bullish candles

Comment: @User4536124 Then I got it wrong. You should not use `close` (which is the same as `close[0]`) as that is the current bar and the value of this `close` changes constantly as price changes as the bar is not finished yet. If you want the check if the recently closed candle is bullish check its `open` price against its `close` price: `closeHigherV1 = close[1] > open[1] `

Comment: @User4536124 I have modified the answer. This is a very mechanical approach but better readable. If you were to increase the number of securities you work with in the script be aware of Pine's limitation of 40 external securities.